# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(1-z^n)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions, geometric-series

Prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(1-z^n)^2}$$
and give the region where is an holomorphic function.

I already know that are holomorphic functions in the open disk $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ but I don't know how to prove the equality.

Comment: Use the geometric series for the summand on the LHS and exchange the summations.

Comment: Sorry, What is LHS? @metamorphy

Comment: Left Hand Side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}&=\sum_{n\ge1}n\sum_{k\ge1}z^{nk}\\
&=\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{n\ge1}nz^{nk}\\
&=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{z^k}{(1-z^k)^2},
\end{align}
where you can exchange the order of sums because of absolute convergence.

Comment: I see where I was stuck, I had to derive $\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^(n-1)$ from the geometric serie of $\frac {1}{1-w}$ and then use what you wrote. Thanks, it gave me the hint I needed. @KentaS